# CSS technique for a horizontal line to the left of text with text align centre

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve a solution where a horizontal line appears to the left of the text but the text remains centre aligned. Please see image below.

I've also added my mark-up below. I'm currently using Bootstrap 4.

[image]

```
     <div class="text-center nav-items">
    <ul>
      <div class="pb-5">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><h2 class="sidebar-first-item">About</h2></a>
        </li>
        <p>Behind the brand // Meet the team</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pb-5">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><h2>Our Work</h2></a>
        </li>
        <p>Take a look at our marvelous creations</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pb-5">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><h2>Services</h2></a>
        </li>
        <p>Learn more about what we can do for you</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pb-5">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><h2 class="sidebar-last-item">Contact</h2></a>
        </li>
        <p>Get in touch today. Let's make some magic</p>
      </div>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: **Your HTML is invalid** and needs to be fixed first. `li` can only be a child of `ul` or `ol`, and `ul` can only have `li` children. When you have fixed that, show what you have attempted so far.

Comment: **Really**, you cannot go with invalid HTML. There is no valid "but it works" argument here. **Invalid HTML is never - not in ONE single case in this world! - an option, no matter what your browser does with it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pseudo-elements to do so:

```
.sidebar-first-item {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar-first-item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 45%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/xxEaQYg

Comment: Please reserve syntax highlighting for when it is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

First cleanup your html, a `<ul>` list may not have children other than `<li>`, `<script>` or `<template>` elements (see [The Unordered List element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)). Hence remove the div's inside the `<ul>` and add their classes to the `<li>`.

A solution to your design problem is to add a  element before and after your anchor elements, size them (width) with a percentage you like and set a min-width for the anchor, so you have a nice responsive layout also on small devices. This creates an equal width red line

If you want the red line to align with the width of the text, you can make your anchor non-breaking white space and a set a padding, so the red line comes as close as defined in the padding towards the text.

```css
.redline,
.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: red;
}

.spacer {
  height: 0px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li a {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0px solid gold;
  padding: 0 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li p {
  width: 100%; margin:-50px 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="text-center nav-items">
  <ul>
    <li class="pb-5">

      <span class="redline"></span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="sidebar-first-item">About</h2>
      </a>
      <span class="spacer"></span>

    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Take a look at our marvelous creations</p>
    </li>



    <li class="pb-5">
      <span class="redline"></span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Our Work</h2>
      </a>
      <span class="spacer"></span>     
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Behind the brand // Meet the team</p>
    <li>



  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is where a CSS pseudo element can come into play! A pseudo element can be used to place designs before or after an element.

I added a class called horizontal-line to your h2.

```
<div class="text-center nav-items">
<ul>
  <div class="pb-5">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><h2 class="horizontal-line sidebar-first-item">About</h2></a>
    </li>
    <p>Behind the brand // Meet the team</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pb-5">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><h2>Our Work</h2></a>
    </li>
    <p>Take a look at our marvelous creations</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pb-5">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><h2>Services</h2></a>
    </li>
    <p>Learn more about what we can do for you</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pb-5">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><h2 class="sidebar-last-item">Contact</h2></a>
    </li>
    <p>Get in touch today. Let's make some magic</p>
  </div>
</ul>
```

The CSS will look like this.

```
.horizontal-line {
 position: relative;
}

.horizontal-line::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #DE657D;
}
```

By adding the pseudo element it will know to place it before any content with that class name. In this case, we are leaving content blank and placing in

https://jsfiddle.net/rc463gb8/1/